# SQLinjection in SQLite: How to select a column with whitespace without use it?

Tags: sql-injection

So, I'm trying to do a SQL injection in a ctf application that removes all whitespace in form parameters, so I can't use it. To perform my query I used /**/ to insert whitespace and I could perform many queries using something like:

`1'/**/UNION/**/SELECT/**/column/**/FROM/**/table;--`

I'm injecting SQL in a SELECT query.

Now I have a problem: The column name that I need has one whitespace, something like: `my column`. So my query would be like:

`1'/**/UNION/**/SELECT/**/"my column"/**/FROM/**/table;--`

But I need to remove this whitespace. I tried to use hex encoding: `SELECT/**/X'hex_ecoding'/**/...` but it always return the same blob structure.

I don't have the entire source code. All that I know is that the query (in the code) is like `'SELECT column FROM table WHERE id=' + idvar` that allows SQL injection. I'm providing a parameter `1' UNION SELECT column_with_whitespace FROM table2`. This parameter is the id that will be inserted in the query string. I can't use whitespaces because the application removes them. So basically, I only have the control of the second SELECT query, I couldn't use WITH with UNION query.

Is there any way to do this in SQLite?